# Asyncio lock acquire task at end of event loop

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Consider the code below

```
import asyncio

async def waiter2(lock):
      print('2 waiting for it ...')
      async with lock:
            print('2 ... got it!')

async def waiter(lock):
      print('waiting for it ...')
      async with lock:
            print('... got it!')

async def main():
      lock = asyncio.Lock()
      await lock.acquire() 

      waiter_task = asyncio.create_task(waiter(lock))
      waiter_task = asyncio.create_task(waiter2(lock))

      await asyncio.sleep(2)

      lock.release()
      print("released")
      
      asyncio.run(main())
```

When executed, this is the output:

```
waiting for it ...
2 waiting for it ...
released
... got it!
```

after the main function ends, the event loop only cares to finish the first waiter, but the lock acquire condition for the second waiter are met by the end of the first waiter, what is the technical reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` for the tasks to finish. In `asyncio` only one task is running at time. So when you release the lock your main function and the whole program will finish without switching to `waiter2` task.

```py
import asyncio


async def waiter2(lock):
    print("2 waiting for it ...")
    async with lock:
        print("2 ... got it!")


async def waiter(lock):
    print("waiting for it ...")
    async with lock:
        print("... got it!")


async def main():
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    await lock.acquire()

    waiter_task_1 = asyncio.create_task(waiter(lock))
    waiter_task_2 = asyncio.create_task(waiter2(lock))

    await asyncio.sleep(2)

    lock.release()
    print("released")

    await waiter_task_1   # <--- wait for waiter_task_1 to finish
    await waiter_task_2   # <--- wait for waiter_task_2 to finish


asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
waiting for it ...
2 waiting for it ...
released
... got it!
2 ... got it!
```

Comment: But why does the first waiter function end without awaiting for the tasks?

Comment: @KrypticCoconut I would start looking at source code of `asyncio.Lock`. There's call `_wake_up_first()` in `release()` method: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L138

Comment: @KrypticCoconut The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock.release) is lacking, in the source code is written *" If any other coroutines are blocked waiting for the lock to become
        unlocked, allow exactly one of them to proceed."*

Comment: Thanks for looking into sc, but isn't that referring to when lock.release itself is called. The event is jumping onto the first waiter after the main function has ended, as the first waiter prints `... got it!` after `released' is printed

Comment: @KrypticCoconut You need to go *deeper*. The `_wake_up_first()` is calling `Future.set_result`, which in turn is calling `Loop._call_soon`. The callback isn't called immediately.